# Ajuda sobre uma consulta JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta usando criteria do JPA, seria o seguinte:

Irei passar 2 datas dataInicial e uma DataFinal e uma placa do veiculo como posso fazer essa consulta?

OBS: A tabela que vou consultar seria Servico e ela possui um Carro onde esse carro teria uma placa, creio eu que até esse ponto está correto.

```
public List<Servico> buscarServicoDeVeiculoEntreDatas(Date diaServico, Date diaGarantia, Carro carro) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Servico> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Servico.class);

        Root<Servico> s = criteriaQuery.from(Servico.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        ParameterExpression<Date> dataInicial = builder.parameter(Date.class, "dataInicial");
        ParameterExpression<Date> dataFinal = builder.parameter(Date.class, "dataFinal");

    criteriaQuery.where(builder.between(s.get("data"), dataInicial, dataFinal));

    TypedQuery<Servico> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        Calendar dataIni = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataIni.setTime(Seta sua data aqui);
        dataIni.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        dataIni.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        dataIni.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Calendar dataFin = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataFin.setTime(Seta sua data aqui);
        dataFin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        dataFin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        dataFin.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        query.setParameter("dataInicial", dataIni.getTime());
        query.setParameter("dataFinal", dataFin.getTime());


    return query.getResultList();
```

Adiciona esse trecho ao final e adapta para seu projeto.

Comment: nesse método setTime o que eu coloco no parametro? OBS: Quero buscar por data e não por Hora.